# compare wscript.arguments and string

Tags: vbscript, args

I want to compare an wscript.argument that I got to the vbs to a string, so depending in that comparation one action or another is performed. I have tried this, but I get an error. How can I solve it? How can I make the type comparation?

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
Set accessPath = args.Item(5) 
    If accessPath = "-" Then
    objExcel.Cells(15, 3).Value = " " 
    Else
    objExcel.Cells(15, 3).Value = accessPath
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Dim accessPath : accessPath = Wscript.Arguments(5)

If accessPath = "-" Then
    objExcel.Cells(15, 3).Value = " " 
Else
    objExcel.Cells(15, 3).Value = accessPath
End If
```

Bear in mind that arguments start at 0, so by looking at `Wscript.Arguments(5)` you're actually looking at the sixth entry on the command line.

Finally you may want to also check the value of `Wscript.Arguments.Count` to ensure you have had enough arguments passed, otherwise an error will be thrown.